# How to get sample size for purposive sampling?

Tags: sampling

How do I get a sample size if I'm using purposive sampling for my study? It's a sensory evaluation for a food product development but there are exclusion criteria so my adviser suggested to use purposive sampling. We will conduct it on a grade school but the respondents will only be 12 yr old students who are willing and qualified for the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Determining the sample size for purposive sampling involves selecting individuals or cases based on specific criteria that are relevant to the research objectives. Unlike random sampling methods, where sample size calculations are often based on statistical considerations, purposive sampling relies on selecting participants who possess certain characteristics or qualities deemed important for the study.

Here are some steps to consider when determining the sample size for purposive sampling:

1. **Define the Population**: Identify the population from which you will draw your sample. Purposive sampling is often used when the population is small or when specific characteristics are of interest.
2. **Specify Inclusion Criteria**: Clearly define the criteria that individuals or cases must meet to be included in the sample. These criteria should align with the research objectives and the characteristics of interest.
3. **Consider Diversity**: Aim for diversity within the purposive sample to ensure a comprehensive representation of the characteristics or perspectives under study. This may involve selecting participants from different demographic groups or with varying levels of experience.
4. **Reach Saturation**: In qualitative research, sample size is often determined by data saturation, where new information or insights cease to emerge with additional participants. As such, the sample size may be flexible and determined by the point of saturation rather than a predetermined number.
5. **Consult Relevant Literature**: Reviewing existing research or consulting experts in the field may provide insights into appropriate sample sizes for similar studies using purposive sampling methods.
6. **Consider Practical Constraints**: Take into account practical constraints such as time, budget, and resources when determining the sample size. Purposive sampling can be resource-intensive, especially when targeting specific or hard-to-reach populations.
7. **Pilot Testing**: Consider conducting pilot testing or a small-scale study to assess the feasibility of the sampling approach and refine the inclusion criteria before proceeding with the main study.
8. **Continuous Evaluation**: Throughout the research process, continuously evaluate the adequacy and representativeness of the purposive sample. Adjustments to the sample size or inclusion criteria may be necessary based on emerging findings or changing research needs.

It's essential to remember that the goal of purposive sampling is not to achieve statistical representativeness but rather to select participants who can provide valuable insights or fulfill specific criteria relevant to the research objectives. Therefore, the sample size for purposive sampling may vary depending on the context, research goals, and practical considerations.